# SQL userts ranking depending on reputation points

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How get users ranking depending on reputation points.
Exclude 'super_admin' and 'staff' roles.

**MY QUERY:**
When I make my request including all users the ranking works like desired, but
when I make my request excluding users who have the role 'super_admin' and 'staff' the ranking is wrong.

```
SELECT u.id, u.rank 
FROM (
      SELECT u.id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank
      FROM users u, (SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r
      ORDER BY u.reputation DESC, u.register_date ASC
     ) AS u
LEFT JOIN users_role ur ON ur.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.id = ur.role_id
WHERE r.key_role NOT IN ('super_admin','staff')
AND u.id=3
```

**TABLES:**

```
users table

ID    REPUTATION     REGISTERED_DATE
1     6000           2018-05-20 14:15:10
2     20             2018-05-22 14:15:10
3     2000           2018-05-25 14:15:10
4     350            2018-05-27 14:15:10
5     14             2018-05-27 19:15:10
6     0              2018-05-28 14:15:10
7     584            2018-05-29 14:15:10
8     54             2018-05-30 14:15:10


users_roles table

ID    USER_ID        ROLE_ID
1     1              1
2     2              2
3     3              3
4     4              3
5     5              3
6     6              3
7     7              3
8     8              3


roles table

ID    NAME              KEY_ROLE
1     Super Admin       super_admin
2     Staff             staff
3     Registered user   registered_user
```

Comment: What is this condition `...AND u.id=3`?

Comment: @forpas I want get the rank of the user id 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on your code:

```
SELECT id, rank FROM (
  SELECT u.id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank 
  FROM (
      SELECT u.id
      FROM users u
      LEFT JOIN users_roles ur ON ur.user_id = u.id
      LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.id = ur.role_id
      WHERE r.key_role NOT IN ('super_admin','staff')
      ORDER BY u.reputation DESC, u.registered_date ASC
     ) AS u
  ,(SELECT @rownum :=0 ) r
) AS t 
WHERE id=3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4h2KN1txL8eqPMzT3KkeKD/1)
I included all the conditions in the inner query.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you want:

```
SELECT u.id, u.rank 
FROM (SELECT u.id, (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS rank
      FROM users u CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rownum := 0 ) r
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM users_role ur JOIN
                             roles r
                             ON r.id = ur.role_id
                        WHERE ur.user_id = u.id AND
                              r.key_role NOT IN ('super_admin', 'staff')
                       )
      ORDER BY u.reputation DESC, u.register_date ASC
     ) u
WHERE u.id = 3;
```

In particular, users with multiple roles will not affect the ranking.

Note that in newer versions of MySQL, variables do not work well with `ORDER BY`, so you need an additional subquery.  In the newest versions, you would simply use window functions.